# Как "включить" слайдер только на определённом медиазапросе.

Tags: html, css, media-queries, slick.js

В адаптивной (на мобилках) версии сайта хочу блок с иконками отображать через слайдер. Но на других разрешениях этот блок должен обычно выглядеть. 
Никогда такого не делал, подскажите как реализовать?

Слайдер подключу slick slide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (window.innerWidth <= 479) {
 $('.single-item').slick();
} else { ... };
```

Думаю JS как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches) ....
```

так точнее будет